# Slack webhook API file_created and file_shared

Tags: webhooks, slack, slack-api

I am working with slack webhook. Trying to understand the event API.

I am getting confused with `file_created` and `file_shared` events. What is the difference between them? Gone through the official documentation but did not worked for me.

Also, we receive file_id and id when an event is triggered, both ids are same. Is there any difference between them?

use cases always help to understand :)

Comment: I wonder why you mention Slack webhooks since they have nothing to do with file uploads, file sharing and events. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The [`file_created`](https://api.slack.com/events/file_created) event is triggered once a new file is uploaded. At this point also a new file_id for that file is created.

Files belong to a user and will not be visible to anyone on a Slack workspace until it is shared in a conversation or channel.

Once a file is shared in a channel / conversation the [`file_shared`](https://api.slack.com/events/file_shared) event is triggered. Sharing a file can be done during the initial upload (which usually is the case - so both events will occur together) or later.

The same file can be also be shared in multiple channels and each time the `file_shared` event will be triggered.

Comment: I don't know the difference between id and file_id in the file events, maybe someone else can add this information?

Comment: id is for the message itself, file_id is for the file object